# How to check field properties in Controller of MVC Razor Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a requirement to check attribute values of a form field in controller, so i have simple textbox

now i want to check in my controller either it was disabled or not? any one guide me how to achieve this? i have searched alot on Google but i found nothing, formcollection is not providing anything either.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what attribute value you want ?

Comment: are you trying to tell if a text box is passed back to the controller empty?

Comment: @Robert - I believe the OP wants to check the textbox's attributes, i.e. if the textbox is disabled when passed to the controller.

Comment: yes if textbox was disabled then i should come to know in controller, similarly readonly etc.. properties that a normal html control has.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to check whether the textbox itself is disabled. You could use a checkbox and a line of javascript that disable's the checkbox if the user selects it. Then in your controller you can check to see if the boolean value you recieved from the checkbox is true.

```
public ActionResult SomeController (bool IsChecked)
{
    if(isChecked){
       //Do something
    }
    return //something
 }

 if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
      $("#textbox1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller will only have access to the values contained in the form collection, and textbox attributes are not passed with the request (other than the `value` attribute).

You could add a hidden field to track such data. The hidden field will be passed with the request, and can contain whatever you want. To populate the field, you would most likely use JavaScript, but you could also set the value server-side if you *knew* the element's attributes when the view was rendered.

Or, perhaps you could look at the *cause* of the change. For example, if selecting a certain option in a `<select>` causes the change, you could look at the posted value of the `<select>` and infer that the textbox must be disabled.

All said, I'm not sure why you want to do it. Usually it is better to manage the root cause of the action (i.e. why did you set the attributes?) rather than the side effect.